# Is it possible to recreate IKEA's functionality using Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

A client is looking to achieve the same level of functionality as can be seen on Ikea's room set pages for an ecommerce site but doesn't want to use flash.

[Ikea Room Set With Flash](http://www.ikea.com/ca/en/catalog/categories/departments/bedroom/)

Although complex, would this be possible using Ajax?

Thanks for your insight in advance.

Regards

Jonathan

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/) and [jCarouselLite](http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/). Also, ajax is not a way to 'make stuff look really good' but rather it is a way for browsers to make out-of-band requests in the background.

Answer (score 0):

when there is a will there is a way! :)

review this RIAs to get some ideas on what could be done on client side... (some may use flash though... but many of them are Ajax based).

edit: sorry forgot the link:
http://www.insideria.com/2009/09/50-most-usable-rias.html

Answer (score 0):

It does not look overly complicated. The only issue I see is the full-screen mode - I don't see how you are goign to do this without Flash.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any one plugin that will do all that the IKEA flash is capable of, but here are a few links to jquery plugins that are similar (this is by no means a comprehensive list)

- Tooltips/Modal windows

  - [Rollovers](http://www.ilovecolors.com.ar/rollovers-tooltips-jquery/)
  - [FancyBox](http://fancybox.net/example)
- Image Zooming:

  - [maxImage](http://www.aaronvanderzwan.com/maximage/)
  - [HighSlide](http://highslide.com/): not free for commerical use =(
- Full screen gallery

  - [maxImage](http://www.aaronvanderzwan.com/maximage/)
  - [Supersized](http://www.buildinternet.com/project/supersized/)